# Create a bar plot in pandas with dates on x-axis, one bar for each value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
>>> df
>>> StartDate         Port  Count
2011-08-10 11:07:10   3128  10
2011-08-10 11:07:40     80   1
2011-08-10 11:07:40    443   1
2011-08-10 11:07:40   3128  10
2011-08-10 11:08:00    443   1
2011-08-10 11:08:00   3128   9
2011-08-10 11:08:20     80   1
```

I want to create a histogram where on x-axis will be 'StartDate' periods, on y-axis will be count and there will be one column for each value from the 'Port' column.

I tried using groupby() with df.plot.bar(), but it does not give me the result I want. How could I do it?

[image: Ok, not the best drawing, but should give the idea. y-axis is a count, each bar represents the value from the 'Port' column]
Ok, not the best drawing, but should give the idea. y-axis is a count, each bar represents the value from the 'Port' column. On x-axis are dates from the first column

Comment: Can you do a mock drawing and link it up here. In the current form, the question is hard to understand.

Comment: I updated with a sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) for reshaping and last use [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['StartDate','Port'])['Count'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
Port                 80    443   3128
StartDate                            
2011-08-10 11:07:10     0     0    10
2011-08-10 11:07:40     1     1    10
2011-08-10 11:08:00     0     1     9
2011-08-10 11:08:20     1     0     0

df1.plot.bar()
```

Alternative solution  with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='StartDate', columns='Port', values='Count')
print (df1)
Port                 80    443   3128
StartDate                            
2011-08-10 11:07:10   NaN   NaN  10.0
2011-08-10 11:07:40   1.0   1.0  10.0
2011-08-10 11:08:00   NaN   1.0   9.0
2011-08-10 11:08:20   1.0   NaN   NaN

df1.plot.bar()
```

Comment: Thank you. But it is not exactly what I want. Sorry, I badly described it

Comment: Please check solution now.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad can help! Good luck!